# Passport-local returns 400 error, never queries database

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-local

I'm trying to use [passport.js](http://passportjs.org/) in my node.js app to authenticate a user with MongoDB. I never hit success.

In the post, I send         "email": "email@gmail.com",
        "password": "test"

```
var passport = require('passport')
   , LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;


app.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/',
                               failureRedirect: '/fail' })
);

passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
      emailField: 'email',
      passwordField: 'passw',
   },
function (emailField, passwordField, done) {
   process.nextTick(function () {
      db.collection(users, function (error, collection) {
         if (!error) {
            collection.findOne({
               'email': emailField,
               'password': passwordField
            }, function (err, user) {
               if (err) {
                  return done(err);
               }
               if (!user) {
                  console.log('this email does not exist');
                  return done(null, false);
               }
                  return done(null, user);
            });
         } else {
            console.log(5, 'DB error');
         }
      });
   });
}));
```

In MongoDB 'users' collection:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "533b5283e4b09d8a1148b4c4"
    },
    "email": "email@gmail.com",
    "password": "test"
}
```

Maybe I am not connecting to the database right, I'm not sure.

Also, when I log all throughout the function, I don't get ANY logs. I simply get

```
 POST /login 302 7ms - 39b  
 GET /fail 404 3ms
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I think I may be missing something but I'm not sure exactly how to structure this. In the other function where I'm writing to the database I have to use:

```
var uristring = 
process.env.MONGOLAB_URI || 
process.env.MONGOHQ_URL || 
'mongodb://<myurlhere>';

mongo.connect(uristring, function (err, db) {
```

---

**Here is the updated code**

requiring these:

```
   , passport = require('passport')
   , LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
```

using these:

```
// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({ secret: 'keyboard cat'}));
app.use(logfmt.requestLogger());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(app.router);

// User authentication passport

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    {
        usernameField: 'email',
        passwordField: 'passw',
    },
    function (userId, password, done) {
        // removed process.nextTick
        console.log('Hey! no more 400 error!');
        db.collection(users, function (error, collection) {
            if (!error) {
                collection.findOne({
                    'email': userId,
                    'password': password
                }, function (err, user) {
                    if (err) {
                        return done(err);
                    }
                    if (!user) {
                        console.log('this email does not exist');
                        return done(null, false);
                    }
                    return done(null, user);
                });
            } else {
                console.log(5, 'DB error');
            }
        });
    } 
));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});

app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), function(req, res) {
   console.log('SUCCESS WOOOO');
   // If this function gets called, authentication was successful.
   // `req.user` contains the authenticated user.
   //res.redirect('/users/' + req.user.username);
  });
```

This code always gives me `POST /login 400 10ms` when posting to /login. All my other routes work fine.

Comment: Is your code in one file or broken into modules?  I ask because the order in which you call things can matter.  Also, did you leave the `process.nextTick` in your code for a specific reason?  I believe it is in the example code to 'mock' the delay of a DB call but isn't actually needed.

Comment: No, I just started this app and currently this function is in app.js. I plan on breaking making this more modular after I get authentication working.

Comment: I've tried so many things. Currently I'm getting a 404.

`app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), function(req, res) {`
`console.log('SUCCESS WOOOO');`
`// If this function gets called, authentication was successful.`
`// req.user contains the authenticated user.`
`//res.redirect('/users/' + req.user.username);`
`});`

Comment: I can't figure out how to do a block of code in a comment. 4 spaces doesn't work. backtics work but don't add new line.

Comment: You're getting a 404 on posting to `/login`?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I meant 400. @MattBakaitis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ended up being an issue with Postman(which I've used soooo many times without problem).

Once I used a real html form it worked fine. Maybe a headers thing?

Comment: I've been having similar problems with Postman. Even with the Interceptor extension turned on it doesn't seem to maintain any notion of session persistence (via cookies).

Comment: Had the same issue with postman.  Originally I was sending the data using form-data and it had been working.  Once I had updated to the latest express and connect version.  I had to use x-www-form-urlencoded

Answer (score 20):

**1) The dreaded HTTP 400 error**

Passport throws an HTTP 400 error when the username and/or password are not set.

See the source around line 75 where `Strategy.prototype.authenticate` throws a ['missing credentials'](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local/blob/96a4727243588a6f835efefd9e2511c0da1060e6/lib/strategy.js#L75) error.

**2) Diagnosing the cause**

In your code, you have the block:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
      emailField: 'email',
      passwordField: 'passw',
   },
```

But `emailField` isn't recognized by passport.  Back in the [source code](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local/blob/master/lib/strategy.js#L49), we see that passport is looking for:

```
this._usernameField = options.usernameField || 'username';
this._passwordField = options.passwordField || 'password';
```

This is why the HTTP 400 is being thrown in this specific situation.

**4) Fixing the problem**

I've edited your original code to what I believe will work (better) than the original.  I took some liberty when editing to remove the `process.nextTick` and renamed a few things.  I hope you are a forgiving person. :)

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    {
        usernameField: 'email',
        passwordField: 'passw',
    },
    function (userId, password, done) {
        // removed process.nextTick
        console.log('Hey! no more 400 error!');
        db.collection(users, function (error, collection) {
            if (!error) {
                collection.findOne({
                    'email': userId,
                    'password': password
                }, function (err, user) {
                    if (err) {
                        return done(err);
                    }
                    if (!user) {
                        console.log('this email does not exist');
                        return done(null, false);
                    }
                    return done(null, user);
                });
            } else {
                console.log(5, 'DB error');
            }
        });
    } 
));
```

**5) Some closing notes:**

- You could also edit the form input attributes to match passport's expected defaults.  See the [passport documentation](http://passportjs.org/guide/username-password/) for guidance.
- I can't guarantee the MongoDB call will work, but this should get you past the HTTP 400.  If the database call has issues, that's almost certainly a new question because a different set of code and modules are involved.
- When using passport, it's worth visiting the project GitHub page and reading through the source.  There are often comments in the source that (a) aren't in the other docs or (b) are close to the code they describe...so things are clarified for you even if you aren't a coding guru or whatever.

Comment: I'm still getting a 400. If I could get past the 400, I could probably figure this out. I still can't get any logs either, other than the 400.

I've updated the original post with my changes.

`POST /login 400 10ms`

Comment: I'm posting to http://localhost:3000/login. All my other routes work. I'm sending email and passw

Comment: I've copied just about everything you posted into a one-page app based on the passport-local example for working with express and mongo.  The only time I can get it to 400 is when the attributes in the login form don't match with what passport is expecting.  Sorry I can't do more.  If you figure it out, I'd be interested in hearing what happened.

Comment: For me, the issue was that I wasn't using a body parser, thus my `req.body` was undefined. I thought `passport-local` handled this, but it doesn't. Just had to do an `app.use` on `body-parser`.

Comment: How does this answer not have about 100 upvotes? @MatthewBakaitis, you're a beast.